# "cannot instantiate the type select" while selecting an item from drop down

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
package Saradhi;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LoginAndNavigate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/");

        WebElement frmtime = driver.findElement(By.id("workShift_workHours_from"));

        Select se = new Select(frmtime); // error line
```

I'm getting an error message in the above line.
I have tried importing related packages but still didn't work.

Comment: Select is a abstract class, you can't create instance of it!

Comment: @Simze "Select is a abstract class, you can't create instance of it!" Really? Since when? Have you [checked it](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) before commenting?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi see the import OP which he has done! `org.apache.bcel.generic.Select` and you are requested to check. This is abstract class !

Comment: @Simze yes, I saw. However this wasn't his intention.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing a wrong package. Try

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

instead of

```
import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

And remove this one:

```
import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [Tips for Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)